# How can I disable Spring Boot logging configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and want to completely disable the automatic logging configuration and use SLF4J and logback directly instead.

I've tried the following:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={LoggingApplicationListener.class})
```

Which didn't work.  Is there a way to completely disable the spring boot logging configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Spring uses a property that overrides the configuration set by default and the annotation you're using.

I once had the same problem and I solved it by specifying the following:

```
-Dlogging.config=log4j-live.xml -Dlog4j.debug
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: This only tells spring where to find the config file.  I am trying to completely disable the spring configuration of logging altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Dave Syer's answer. I think it is the best thing you can do to erase Spring Boot default logging config.

[Spring Boot programmatic logging configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507341/spring-boot-programmatic-logging-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to configure`JAVA_OPTS`, you can override behaviour of `SpringBootServletInitializer` as described in [Spring Boot: LoggingApplicationListener interfering with Application Server logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609996/spring-boot-loggingapplicationlistener-interfering-with-application-server-logg)