# Can I set Spring Boot's log location programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, logback

Spring Boot's logging location can be set using the `logging.file` property in `application.properties`. However I want to set the location programmatically. My logic is not based on any Spring beans, only on trial-and-error because the same code has to run across different environments which may have different security configurations.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html):

> Since logging is initialized before the `ApplicationContext` is created, it isn’t possible to control logging from `@PropertySources` in Spring `@Configuration` files. System properties and the conventional Spring Boot external configuration files work just fine.) [sic]

So I know I can't use `@Configuration` files, but can I use some other way like a static initialiser and still manage to set the logging location programmatically?

(NOTE: I'm personally using SLF4J with Logback, but Spring Boot's logging framework is meant to cope with different logging facades/implementations and in fact uses Commons Logging internally.)

(NOTE 2: Some people have noted this as a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507341/spring-boot-programmatic-logging-configuration)...but that question seems to be talking more about configuring the actual logging implementation, whereas this question is about Spring Boot's own configuration. In fact, I cannot immediately determine from those answers how to solve my specific question, as noted in a comment underneath the relevant answer. The answer to that other question focusses mainly on how to get the code to load at the correct point of context initialization, whereas my question is about how to set the logging location.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot programmatic logging configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507341/spring-boot-programmatic-logging-configuration)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the same requirements. Have you been able to solve it somehow?  In the comment to the answer with the SpringApplicationInitializer you said that it will not work like this. What other solution did you finally find?

Comment: @André sorry, I have no idea because this was years ago when I worked at a previous company and I can't remember. I assume I just used a static log location such as the user's home directory and some external job to move the log file

Answer (score 1):

There's another answer: [Spring Boot programmatic logging configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507341/spring-boot-programmatic-logging-configuration)

Basically, it's possible to do that via the `SpringApplicationInitializer` (implementing ApplicationContextInitializer)

```
SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MySources.class);
application.addInitializers(new LoggingInitializer());
application.run(args);
```

Comment: Can you give me a bit more detail as to how to accomplish this? A couple of things I don't understand: (1) `SpringApplicationInitializer` and `ApplicationContextInitializer` have one method each (the methods have different signatures). Which method should I put my code into? (2) What methods should I call inside the initializer? Should I do something like wrap the environment and add the extra "logging.file" property and then set it back onto the application context? Or is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: After some further investigation, I don't think this will work at all for this use case. The logging file location is read in `LogFile.get` which is called from `LoggingApplicationListener.initialize`. But this listener method is invoked on the `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` event, which is triggered on (current) line 310 of `SpringApplication`, whereas the `ApplicationContextInitializer` is not invoked until line 327 (both inside the `doRun` method).