# How do I set the logging properties in a spring java configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using a Spring 5 MVC application.  I am trying to get a pure java configuration going.  I notice that my logging is not working.  I have this in my application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.security=ERROR
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Now I am not using application.properties of course,  so how do I set this in a pure Java way in one of my @Configuration classes?

Comment: Store it in the properties object and load the object on startup. Similar to the old fashion approach ?

Comment: What properties object?  I can certainly make one.  How do I annotate/load it?

Comment: Do you actually want to get a pure java configuration? or you just cant make `application.properties` work? i mean `application.properties` is such a clean and straightforward way for lots of setup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you actually want to get a pure java logger configuration, you can setup it like this:

```
public class LoggingInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        //suppose you use default logback (ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext)
        LoggerContext c = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        c.getLogger("ru.varren").setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        c.getLogger("org.springframework.web").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        c.getLogger("org.springframework.security").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        c.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL").setLevel(Level.DEBUG); 
    }
}
```

And then init it in main before the app starts.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class)
                .initializers(new LoggingInitializer())
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

Also take a look at this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20521500/1032167

Comment: This answer is Spring Boot-oriented, as well as the answer you provided a link for, which the original question wasn't (only mentioned Spring 5 / Spring MVC, with relevant tags); without Boot, you can't do `new SpringApplicationBuilder()`